# Error resolving onAction

Tags: java, javafx, upgrade, fxml, fxmlloader

I know this has been asked several times before but none of the answers were a solution for me. I just updated the JDK to java-8-openjdk-amd64 (from jdk7) and these errors just appeared:

```
javafx.fxml.LoadException: Error resolving onAction='#changeStyle', either the event handler is not in the Namespace or there is an error in the script./myapp.fxml:1778
```

Line 1778:

```
<Button layoutX="250.0" layoutY="170.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#changeStyle" text="Reset Style" />
```

Controller .java:

```
public void changeStyle(){
    String url_orig = CUSTOM_HTMLEditor.class.getClassLoader().getResource(pathToOrigCss).toExternalForm();
    String url_1 = CUSTOM_HTMLEditor.class.getClassLoader().getResource(pathToStyle_1Css).toExternalForm();
    String url_tango = CUSTOM_HTMLEditor.class.getClassLoader().getResource(pathToStyle_tangoCss).toExternalForm();
    String url_tango_invers = CUSTOM_HTMLEditor.class.getClassLoader().getResource(pathToStyle_tangoInversCss).toExternalForm();

    root_AnchorPane.getStylesheets().clear();   

    final Toggle selectedToggle = styleToggle.getSelectedToggle();
    int selectedToggleIndex = styleToggle.getToggles().indexOf(selectedToggle);

    switch(selectedToggleIndex)
    {
    case 0:
        root_AnchorPane.getStylesheets().add(url_orig);
        System.out.println("Style changed to original.");
        currentPathToCSS = url_orig;
        break;
    case 1:
        root_AnchorPane.getStylesheets().add(url_1);
        System.out.println("Style changed to style_1.");
        currentPathToCSS = url_1;
        break;
    case 2:
        root_AnchorPane.getStylesheets().add(url_tango);
        System.out.println("Style changed to tango.");
        currentPathToCSS = url_tango;
        break;
    case 3:
        root_AnchorPane.getStylesheets().add(url_tango_invers);
        System.out.println("Style changed to tango_invers.");
        currentPathToCSS = url_tango_invers;
        break;
    default:
        root_AnchorPane.getStylesheets().add(url_orig);
        System.out.println("Style changed to original.");
        currentPathToCSS = url_orig;

    }
}
```

Setting of the controller:

```
<AnchorPane id="root" fx:id="root_AnchorPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="500.0" minWidth="700.0" prefHeight="680.0" prefWidth="1000.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.60" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="de.semproc.hergarten.gui.MemotrainerController">
```

EDIT:
Thanks for the help. It was the static in the method.

Comment: Can you edit the question to show the part where you set the controller?

Comment: I don't think you can specify a `static` method as a handler. (It makes no sense anyway; the handler is a property of a UI component, which is necessarily a property of the controller *instance*.)

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

Add `@FXML` to the method. For example:

```
@FXML public void changeStyle(){
....
....
....
}
```